# Weyl group of $C_2$ in $C_2 \ltimes U(n)$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

Let $C_2$ denote the cyclic group of order $2$ and let $C_2 \ltimes U(n)$ denote the semi-direct product of $C_2$ with the unitary group, where $C_2$ acts on $U(n)$ by complex conjugation.

I want to calculate the Weyl group
$$
W_{C_2 \ltimes U(n)} C_2 = (N_{C_2 \ltimes U(n)} C_2)/C_2.
$$

I believe that the normalizer is $U(n)$, so that the question is equivalent to calculating
$$
U(n)/C_2.
$$

> What is $
> W_{C_2 \ltimes U(n)} C_2 = (N_{C_2 \ltimes U(n)} C_2)/C_2?
> $

My hope is that the answer is $O(n)$, but I cannot prove it. (I do know that $U(n)^{C_2} \cong O(n)$ however.)